# A Try-Catch Block Macro equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#, macros

Here is a sample C++ macro that I use to make my code more readable and reduce the Try-Catch Clutter:

```c++
#define STDTRYCATCH(expr)               \
    try {                               \
        return (expr);                  \
    }                                   \
    catch (const std::exception& ex) {  \
        handleException(ex);            \
    }                                   \
    catch (...) {                       \
        handleException();              \
    }
```

Which can be used as:

```c++
int myClass::Xyz()
{
    STDTRYCATCH(myObj.ReadFromDB());
}
```

Please note that I'm looking for STDTRYCATCH that handles any code stub we enclose with it.Is there an equivalent in C# ?

Comment: You can pass a closure to a static method handling your exception. Not that I think it's a very good idea (granularity of exception handling differs between use cases), but it's possible.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek : Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: Too much syntactic sugar is no good for maintenance.

Comment: Try/catch-em-all exception handling is a very bad practice.  Legitimizing such a practice by hiding it in a macro is evil.

Comment: hiding necessary exception logic within a macro seems to be a maintenance nightmare to me as well.  so do you have some kind of switch or if elseif nightmare of a dispatching logic in handleException()?

Comment: @DieterLücking : That's true. Since I'm new to C# , I'd like to know if there's a way I can reduce try catching all the time by using StdTryCatch macro while improving the code legibility and that's the reason for my asking of this question.

Comment: The only time you should be catching everything and doing something generic with the exception is at the entry point of the program, at which point you can log the exception and gracefully exit the application.  You should only have such entry points approximately once per application, so there'd be no need to have a macro for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write helper:

```
public static class ExcetpionHandler
{
    public static void StdTryCatch(this object instance, Action act)
    {
        try
        {
            act();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var method = instance.GetType().GetMethod("StdException");
            if (method != null)
            {
                method.Invoke(instance, new object[] {ex});
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void StdException(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thrown");
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        this.StdTryCatch(() =>
                         {
                             throw new Exception();
                         });
    }
}
```

and:

```
class Program
{   
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var instance = new MyClass();
        instance.Do();
    }
}
```

But it is not recommeded - due to performance reasons etc - like mentioned in comments.

**EDIT:**
Like ***cdhowie*** mentioned, you can also prepare inteface:

```
public interface IExceptionHandler 
{
    void StdException(Exception ex);
}
```

Then:

```
public static class ExcetpionHandler
{
    public static void StdTryCatch(this IExceptionHandler instance, Action act)
    {
        try
        {
            act();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            instance.StdException(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Your class then need to impelement that interface.

Comment: If you are using the instance-method approach it may be better to have an `interface IStdExceptionHandler { void StdException(Exception ex); }`, then define the extension method with `this IStdExceptionHandler instance` to avoid reflection overhead. If the exception handlers are free functions in the C++ code then it would make more sense to have this be a regular static function that calls out to another static function to handle the exceptions.